# Only the first buffer works in a Double buffer implemented in C++

Tags: c++

I've implemented a double buffering program that reads txt files with buffers that need to be processed using code and c++ on the Internet, and then outputs the processing result in output.txt format, but it doesn't work.

Here's what I want to do:

```
producer routine
buf1 full_flag : 0 , record_count : 1
buf2 full_flag : 0 , record_count : 0
producer routine
buf1 full_flag : 1 , record_count : 2
buf2 full_flag : 0 , record_count : 0
Consumer routine 
buf1 full_flag : 1 , record_count : 3
buf2 full_flag : 0 , record_count : 0
...
Consumer routine 
buf1 full_flag : 1 , record_count : 10
buf2 full_flag : 0 , record_count : 0
producer routine
buf1 full_flag : 1 , record_count : 1
buf2 full_flag : 1 , record_count : 1
Consumer routine 
buf1 full_flag : 1 , record_count : 1
buf2 full_flag : 1 , record_count : 2
```

But it actually works like this:

```
producer routine
buf1 full_flag : 0 , record_count : 1
buf2 full_flag : 0 , record_count : 0
producer routine
buf1 full_flag : 1 , record_count : 2
buf2 full_flag : 0 , record_count : 0
...
Consumer routine 
buf1 full_flag : 1 , record_count : 10
buf2 full_flag : 0 , record_count : 0
producer routine
buf1 full_flag : 1 , record_count : 1
buf2 full_flag : 0 , record_count : 0
Consumer routine 
buf1 full_flag : 1 , record_count : 2
buf2 full_flag : 0 , record_count : 0
```

No matter how much I look at the code, I don't know what to do. The first buffer works well, but it seems that the pointer does not cross over to the second buffer after the operation.

Maybe there's something wrong with the struct or pointer. But I don't know how to deal with this.

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct buf{
    int buf_n;
    int full_flag;
    int record_counter;
    struct buf* next;
};
int main(){
    struct buf buf1, buf2;
    struct buf *to_fill,*to_empty;
    char str[9];
    int state;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char* Pstate;
    int count=0;
    int n=sizeof(str);
    buf1.buf_n = 1;
    buf2.buf_n = 2;
    buf1.full_flag = 0;
    buf2.full_flag = 0;
    buf1.record_counter = 0;
    buf2.record_counter = 0;
    buf1.next = &buf2;
    buf2.next = &buf1;
    to_fill = &buf1;
    to_empty = &buf1;
    FILE* file=fopen("input.txt","rt");
    FILE* file2=fopen("output.txt","wt");
while(1){
wait: 
  if((*to_fill).full_flag == 1) goto Loop;
   Pstate = fgets(str,sizeof(str),file);
   if(Pstate==NULL)
    break;
   fputs(str, stdout);
  if((*to_fill).record_counter > n){
   (*to_fill).full_flag = 0;
   (*to_fill) = *(*to_fill).next;
  }
  (*to_fill).record_counter=1;
  (*to_fill).full_flag=1;
  (*to_fill) = *(*to_fill).next;
  fprintf(file2,"producer routine\n");
  fprintf(file2,"buf1 full_flag : %d , record_count : %d\n", buf1.full_flag, buf1.record_counter);
  fprintf(file2,"buf2 full_flag : %d , record_count : %d\n", buf2.full_flag, buf2.record_counter);
  i++;
  goto Loop;
Loop: 
  if((*to_empty).full_flag == 0) goto wait;
  (*to_empty).record_counter = (*to_empty).record_counter+1;
  fprintf(file2,"Consumer routine \n");
  fprintf(file2,"buf1 full_flag : %d , record_count : %d\n", buf1.full_flag, buf1.record_counter);
  fprintf(file2,"buf2 full_flag : %d , record_count : %d\n", buf2.full_flag, buf2.record_counter);
  if((*to_empty).record_counter > n){
   (*to_empty).full_flag = 0;
   (*to_empty) = *(*to_empty).next;
  }
  count++;
  if(count>1000){
   break;
  goto wait;
  }
 }
 state=fclose(file);
 state=fclose(file2);
 return 0;
}
```

In addition, the code must have an input.txt file in the same path as where the source file was stored.

The contents of the input.txt file:

```
1234567890
```

Comment: Check your tags. `double-buffering` is for image processing. And this looks more like C than C++. Also, `goto` - really? I'm having a really hard time to follow your code.

Comment: You may try to run your code under debugger step by step

Comment: "No matter how much I look at the code, I don't know what to do". You need to (learn how to) **debug** your program.

Comment: I'm sorry I asked a bad question... And thank you for your kind reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very easy for anyone to tell what's wrong - those gotos are very 1965 - but you're assigning to `*to_fill` and `*to_empty` where one would expect assignments to `to_fill` and `to_empty`.
(That assignment makes your two buffers identical. In particular, `to_fill->next` and `to_empty->next` are the same.)

There is also a `goto` *after* a `break`, where it has no effect.

Modernising your code slightly and fixing that assignment makes the flow clearer (outputs removed for clarity):

```
struct buf{
    int buf_n;
    bool is_full;
    int record_counter;
    buf* next;
};

int main(){
    buf buf1 = {1, false, 0};
    buf buf2 = {2, false, 0};
    buf1.next = &buf2;
    buf2.next = &buf1;

    int i = 0;
    char* Pstate = nullptr;
    int count = 0;
    char str[9];
    int n = sizeof(str);

    buf* to_fill = &buf1;
    buf* to_empty = &buf1;
    FILE* file = fopen("input.txt","rt");
    FILE* file2 = fopen("output.txt","wt");

    while(1){
        if(!to_fill->is_full){
            Pstate = fgets(str,sizeof(str),file);
            if(Pstate == NULL)
                break;
            fputs(str, stdout);
            if(to_fill->record_counter > n){
                to_fill->is_full = false;
                to_fill = to_fill->next;
            }
            to_fill->record_counter = 1;
            to_fill->is_full = true;
            to_fill = to_fill->next;
            i++;
        }
        if(to_empty->is_full) {
            to_empty->record_counter += 1;
            if(to_empty->record_counter > n){
                to_empty->is_full = 0;
                to_empty = to_empty->next;
            }
            count++;
            if(count > 1000){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(file2);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, it looks like there are quite a few bugs left - the buffer-switching looks pretty iffy (for instance, you may switch `to_fill` twice, bringing it back to where it started).
Fixing those bugs left as an exercise.